# Is there an option to fetch results of Azure DevOps pipelines?

Tags: jenkins, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, jenkins-plugins

We had our pipelines all stored and triggered in Jenkins but switched to Azure DevOps some time ago.

Is there a way to create a "fetch-result-job" in Jenkins that will fetch te latest result of the Azure DevOps pipeline, so that I can integrate the Jenkins job in our monitoring tool?

We use an internal, self-developed monitoring tool, that only connects to Jenkins, as all of our other regular tests are stored there.
Unfortunately, I havn't found a solution and there is also no way to integrate the Azure pipeline results directly.

Comment: Is there any update about this ticket? Feel free to let me know if the answer can give you some help.

Answer (score 1):

I am afraid that there is no out-of-box method can directly integrate the Azure pipeline results.

> Is there a way to create a "fetch-result-job" in Jenkins that will fetch te latest result of the Azure DevOps pipeline, so that I can integrate the Jenkins job in our monitoring tool?

To meet your requirements, you can use PowerShell script to run Rest API: [Latest - Get](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/latest/get?view=azure-devops-rest-7.1) to get the latest result of the Azure DevOps pipeline in Jenkins.

For example:

```
$token = "PAT"

$url="https://dev.azure.com/{Organization}/{Project}/_apis/build/latest/{DefinitionID}?api-version=7.1-preview.1"

$token = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$($token)"))

$response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Headers @{Authorization = "Basic $token"} -Method Get  -ContentType application/json

echo $response.result
```

The Rest API can return all related information of the latest Pipeline Run. You can set the script output based on your requirement.

In Jenkins, you can use the [PowerShell Plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/powershell/) to run the PowerShell script.